# Count down timer in jMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a test plan which has three parts. Each part have to run for 5 minutes. I am using a while loop to repeat each part. But I can't find a way to tell the while loop to stop after 5 minutes. Is there a countdown or something similar in jmeter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put each part under [Runtime Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller)

Enter 300 (60 seconds * 5) in Runtime field

> Runtime Controller controls how long its children how long its children will run. Controller will run its children until configured Runtime(s) is exceeded.

Answer (score 1):

If it has to be a [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller)

1. Add a [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) before the While Controller
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   SampleResult.setIgnore()
   vars.putObject('before', System.currentTimeMillis())
   ```
3. Use the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) as the While Controller's condition:

   ```
   ${__groovy(1 == 1 && (System.currentTimeMillis() - vars.getObject('before') < 300000),)}
   ```

   replace `1 == 1` with your own expression, it will exit the loop when either your expression becomes `true` or 5 minutes pass, whatever comes the first.

In the above scripts:

- `SampleResult` is basically JMeter's [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)
- `vars` is a shorthand to [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html)

Check out [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) guide for more details on above and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for [JSR223 Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and __groovy() function